# How close all process on new Desktop?

Tags: c#, winapi

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestDesktop
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const int UOI_NAME = 2;
        private const int NormalPriorityClass = 0x00000020;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public int dwProcessId;
            public int dwThreadId;
        }

        private struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public int cb;
            public string lpReserved;
            public string lpDesktop;
            public string lpTitle;
            public int dwX;
            public int dwY;
            public int dwXSize;
            public int dwYSize;
            public int dwXCountChars;
            public int dwYCountChars;
            public int dwFillAttribute;
            public int dwFlags;
            public short wShowWindow;
            public short cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool CreateProcess(
            string lpApplicationName,
            string lpCommandLine,
            IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
            IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
            bool bInheritHandles,
            int dwCreationFlags,
            IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            string lpCurrentDirectory,
            ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
            ref PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
            );

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateDesktop(string lpszDesktop, IntPtr lpszDevice, IntPtr pDevmode, int dwFlags,
            uint dwDesiredAccess, IntPtr lpsa);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SwitchDesktop(IntPtr hDesktop);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool CloseDesktop(IntPtr handle);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetThreadDesktop(IntPtr hDesktop);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetThreadDesktop(int dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool GetUserObjectInformation(IntPtr hObj, int nIndex, IntPtr pvInfo, int nLength,
            ref int lpnLengthNeeded);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();


        private enum DesktopAccess : uint
        {
            DesktopNone = 0,
            DesktopReadobjects = 0x0001,
            DesktopCreatewindow = 0x0002,
            DesktopCreatemenu = 0x0004,
            DesktopHookcontrol = 0x0008,
            DesktopJournalrecord = 0x0010,
            DesktopJournalplayback = 0x0020,
            DesktopEnumerate = 0x0040,
            DesktopWriteobjects = 0x0080,
            DesktopSwitchdesktop = 0x0100,

            GenericAll = (DesktopReadobjects | DesktopCreatewindow | DesktopCreatemenu
                          | DesktopHookcontrol
                          | DesktopJournalrecord | DesktopJournalplayback |
                          DesktopEnumerate | DesktopWriteobjects | DesktopSwitchdesktop),
        }

        public static string GetDesktopName(IntPtr desktopHandle)
        {
            // check its not a null pointer.
            // null pointers wont work.
            if (desktopHandle == IntPtr.Zero) return null;

            // get the length of the name.
            var needed = 0;
            var name = String.Empty;
            GetUserObjectInformation(desktopHandle, UOI_NAME, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref needed);

            // get the name.
            var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(needed);
            var result = GetUserObjectInformation(desktopHandle, UOI_NAME, ptr, needed, ref needed);
            name = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

            // something went wrong.
            if (!result) return null;

            return name;
        }

        public static void KillAllProcess(string desktopName, IntPtr hNewDesktop)
        {
            var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
            var thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

            foreach (var process in processes)
            {
                // check the threads of the process - are they in this one?
                foreach (ProcessThread pt in process.Threads)
                {
                    if (GetDesktopName(GetThreadDesktop(pt.Id)) == desktopName)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(process.ProcessName);
                        if (process.ProcessName != thisProc.ProcessName)
                        {
                            process.Kill();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            const string newDesktopName = "RandomDesktopName";
            // old desktop's handle, obtained by getting the current desktop assigned for this thread
            var hOldDesktop = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());

            // new desktop's handle, assigned automatically by CreateDesktop
            var hNewDesktop = CreateDesktop(newDesktopName, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0, (uint)DesktopAccess.GenericAll, IntPtr.Zero);

            // switching to the new desktop
            SwitchDesktop(hNewDesktop);
            // assigning the new desktop to this thread - so the Form will be shown in the new desktop)
            SetThreadDesktop(hNewDesktop);

            var si = new STARTUPINFO();
            si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
            si.lpDesktop = newDesktopName;

            var pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

            // start the process.
            CreateProcess(null, "explorer.exe", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, true, NormalPriorityClass, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, ref pi);

            var loginWnd = new Form();
            var btn = new Button { Text = "Close" };
            btn.Click += (sender1, ex1) =>
            {
                KillAllProcess(newDesktopName, hNewDesktop);
                loginWnd.Close();
                SwitchDesktop(hOldDesktop);
            };
            loginWnd.Controls.Add(btn);
            Application.Run(loginWnd);


            SwitchDesktop(hOldDesktop);
            CloseDesktop(hNewDesktop);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

How close all process on new Desktop?

I see in console only one string: "TestDesktop".

Function GetThreadDesktop() always return 0, except when process name is "TestDesktop".

I use this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7666/Desktop-Switching

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/716b2e30-dbf6-4871-808f-5985433ab10a/how-close-all-process-on-new-desktop

"I've added "SetLastError=true" to the GetThreadDesktop declaration. After GetThreadDesktop returns IntPtr.Zero, I get Marshal.GetLastWin32Error. I get 5 (=ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) for some processes including explorer.exe and 122 (=ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) for other processes."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestDesktop
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const int UOI_NAME = 2;
        private const int NormalPriorityClass = 0x00000020;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public int dwProcessId;
            public int dwThreadId;
        }

        private struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public int cb;
            public string lpReserved;
            public string lpDesktop;
            public string lpTitle;
            public int dwX;
            public int dwY;
            public int dwXSize;
            public int dwYSize;
            public int dwXCountChars;
            public int dwYCountChars;
            public int dwFillAttribute;
            public int dwFlags;
            public short wShowWindow;
            public short cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool CreateProcess(
            string lpApplicationName,
            string lpCommandLine,
            IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
            IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
            bool bInheritHandles,
            int dwCreationFlags,
            IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            string lpCurrentDirectory,
            ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
            ref PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
            );

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateDesktop(string lpszDesktop, IntPtr lpszDevice, IntPtr pDevmode, int dwFlags,
            uint dwDesiredAccess, IntPtr lpsa);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SwitchDesktop(IntPtr hDesktop);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool CloseDesktop(IntPtr handle);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetThreadDesktop(IntPtr hDesktop);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetThreadDesktop(int dwThreadId);

        public delegate bool EnumDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "EnumDesktopWindows",
        ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr hDesktop, EnumDelegate lpEnumCallbackFunction, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowText",
        ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpWindowText, int nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool GetUserObjectInformation(IntPtr hObj, int nIndex, IntPtr pvInfo, int nLength,
            ref int lpnLengthNeeded);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool CloseWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, ref int lpdwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();


        private enum DesktopAccess : uint
        {
            DesktopNone = 0,
            DesktopReadobjects = 0x0001,
            DesktopCreatewindow = 0x0002,
            DesktopCreatemenu = 0x0004,
            DesktopHookcontrol = 0x0008,
            DesktopJournalrecord = 0x0010,
            DesktopJournalplayback = 0x0020,
            DesktopEnumerate = 0x0040,
            DesktopWriteobjects = 0x0080,
            DesktopSwitchdesktop = 0x0100,

            GenericAll = (DesktopReadobjects | DesktopCreatewindow | DesktopCreatemenu
                          | DesktopHookcontrol
                          | DesktopJournalrecord | DesktopJournalplayback |
                          DesktopEnumerate | DesktopWriteobjects | DesktopSwitchdesktop),
        }

        public static string GetDesktopName(IntPtr desktopHandle)
        {
            // check its not a null pointer.
            // null pointers wont work.
            if (desktopHandle == IntPtr.Zero) return null;

            // get the length of the name.
            var needed = 0;
            var name = String.Empty;
            GetUserObjectInformation(desktopHandle, UOI_NAME, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref needed);

            // get the name.
            var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(needed);
            var result = GetUserObjectInformation(desktopHandle, UOI_NAME, ptr, needed, ref needed);
            name = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

            // something went wrong.
            if (!result) return null;

            return name;
        }

        public static bool KillAllProcess(string desktopName, IntPtr hNewDesktop)
        {
            var collection = new List<string>();
            var thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

            EnumDelegate filter = delegate(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
            {
                var processId = 0;
                var threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, ref processId);
                try
                {
                    if (thisProc.Id != processId)
                    {
                        var proc = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
                        proc.Kill();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            };

            return EnumDesktopWindows(hNewDesktop, filter, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            const string newDesktopName = "RandomDesktopName";
            // old desktop's handle, obtained by getting the current desktop assigned for this thread
            var hOldDesktop = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());

            // new desktop's handle, assigned automatically by CreateDesktop
            var hNewDesktop = CreateDesktop(newDesktopName, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0, (uint)DesktopAccess.GenericAll, IntPtr.Zero);

            // switching to the new desktop
            SwitchDesktop(hNewDesktop);
            // assigning the new desktop to this thread - so the Form will be shown in the new desktop)
            SetThreadDesktop(hNewDesktop);

            var si = new STARTUPINFO();
            si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
            si.lpDesktop = newDesktopName;

            var pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

            // start the process.
            CreateProcess(null, "explorer.exe", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, true, NormalPriorityClass, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, ref pi);

            var loginWnd = new Form();
            var btn = new Button { Text = "Close" };
            btn.Click += (sender1, ex1) =>
            {
                SwitchDesktop(hOldDesktop);
                KillAllProcess(newDesktopName, hNewDesktop);
                loginWnd.Close();
            };
            loginWnd.Controls.Add(btn);
            Application.Run(loginWnd);


            SwitchDesktop(hOldDesktop);
            CloseDesktop(hNewDesktop);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```